# How to store preferences for an application?

Tags: ruby, programming-languages, metaprogramming

I am a newbie in Ruby coming from web development with mainly PHP/SQL. I was thinking about how I store preferences in my application. For instance, if I want to store a path as `default_path` and have that set also when the user restarts the application.

In the web world one would probably store this in a database or XML. Database seems overkill for a standalone application. But I am unsure wheter XML/YAML/Other-Write-Format is the way to go. And if so, where should I store these preferences? Should they be, for instance on a Mac, in ~/Library/MyAppName?

Comment: Is this for a desktop application, or a web application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby gives you another method for storing data called [Marshaling](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ospace.html#S6).  This will let you store a class/object to a file and reconstitute it later.  If all of your user preferences are stored in a single object (or you can create an object which can hold all of the data that you need), it may be easiest to marshal the data instead of writing import/export routines to a text-based format or trying to pull in an additional library or gem.

As to where on the disk to store the data, that's up to you.  Most platforms have a standard location for storing application data based on whether it's available to a single user or all users.  It's usually safest to follow the common practice on your target platform of choice.

**Update:**  The simplest [example](http://ssscripting.wordpress.com/2010/04/21/ruby-marshal-example/) of marshaling would probably be this: Say that you have a class called `UserPrefs` that you use to store all of your user preferences.  You can use the following code to store the preferences data into a file:

```
my_prefs = UserPrefs.new
# ... Fill in the 'my_prefs' object with the user's preferences, etc ...

# Store the object into a file
File.open("user_prefs.data", "wb") do |file|
   Marshal.dump(my_prefs, file)
end
```

The next time that you load the application, you can restore those preferences using the following:

```
# Load prefs from file
my_prefs = nil
File.open("user_prefs.data", "rb") {|f| my_prefs = Marshal.load(f)}
```

At this point, the `my_prefs` object should be exactly the same as it was when the marshaling code was originally run.  This essentially lets you take a 'snaphot' of an object at one point in time (say, when your program shuts down) and restore it later (say, when your program loads).  Internally, all of the data in the structure is encoded into a single string and that string is what is stored to disk; the Marshal module simply takes care of the encoding and decoding for you.

[Here](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/object_serialization.html) is another example of using marshaling to store and retrieve data.

The default encode/decode routines built into the Marshal module are usually sufficient for most data-storing classes.  Particularly complex classes may have problems, and if that is the case then you can define your own encode and decode methods (the [first link](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ospace.html#S6) includes an example of defining custom methods).

Some types of data, however, cannot be marshaled (things like handles to open files, `Proc` objects, etc) since they don't normally persist across Ruby sessions.  If you are needing to marshal a class that includes members like this that `Marshal` doesn't like, you can use custom encode/decode functions to marshal the rest of the class and omit the problematic members.

Comment: That seems like a good option. But I cannot find anything on it that's close to what I am trying to do and I am having a hard time understanding how to use it. Could you be kind and find some reference(i.e an url) where I can learn more about Marshalling and using it to store preferences. It seems like Marshalling can be used for a lot of stuff, not just for storing data, right?

Comment: @maetthew- See my updated answer for some additional links and sample code.

Answer (score 2):

I like using YAML because it's very easily read/written by a lot of languages, making it possible for several apps to share the same configuration info. It's a well documented standard so there should be very little chance of data falling into a hole with it.

Also, because it's easy for a human to understand, and doesn't take any special tools to change, it works nicely for any data that might occasionally change in an app, either for fine-tuning or to enable special behaviors.

A little creative coding on your part that periodically checks the last modified time of the YAML file could make it so your app would modify its behavior on the fly as the prefs file is tweaked. I had a big app I didn't want to shut down for changes and set up that behavior. It ran three weeks straight, and I tweaked its operating parameters via its config file. It would read the file every minute and inherit any changes to its parameters on the fly.

Databases are a good way to store parameters/preferences if it's a centralized server or web-based app. For something distributed that runs on individual machines it makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! A very good and just excellent answer. This is the top answer unless @bta can find a good reference on storing preferences with Marshalling that will tip the favor. Otherwise I will accept this one in a day or two.

Comment: Oh great. It's a bidding war like eBay. Well, just remember that YAML was DESIGNED for this sort of problem, unlike XML or JSON. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I saw some applications using [ruby gconf2](http://ruby-gnome2.sourceforge.jp/hiki.cgi?cmd=view&p=tut-gconf&key=gconf2)